# OpenSSL on Tomcat 7 client cert authorization

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https, openssl, authorization

I'm new with `SSL,OpenSSL` but I can't found an answer so I must ask.I have project - **dynamic web aplication** running on tomcat, I configure SSL and it works,I set **clientAuth="true"** for client cert and its works too but problem name is Distribution points. Aplication use cards with client cert and sometimes I need to revoke some client cert so I revoke client cert and generate or update `crl` list, but after that I can log on in aplication with revoked cert in other way server don't know that this client is revoked.Is any way that can I check if client cert is revoked or not I have -`Dcom.sun.security.enableCRLDP=true` but nothing happen.
I can't use setting in tomcat `crlFile="http://www.somesite/crllist.pem"` on other way is here some way how to check client cert on "library side" I mean `crl` is in client cert too so can I check this some way ?